# CreateProcess failed with error code '740' in Windows7 64bit

Tags: c++, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, uac

I am using VS2005 in Windows 7 64bit platform. One of my application is trying to create a new process using `CreateProcess` API. While creating a process, API returns error 0. I checked the error code using `GetLastError()`, I got `740`: *The Requested Operation Requires Elevation*. Application that trying to create the new process has Administrative privileges.

I use the following code to create process:

```
// Create the process using modified stratup info
int nRetVal = CreateProcess( (LPSTR)strFullPath.c_str(),
                             (LPSTR)strCmdLine.c_str(),
                             0, 0, FALSE, 0 , 0,
                             (LPSTR)strWorkingDir.c_str(),
                             //NULL,
                             &StartupInfo, &ProcInfo );
```

How can I launch a new process from my application without turning off UAC?

While building the parent application I am getting the following warning:

> App.manifest: manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "requestedPrivileges" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2".

Regards,
Nixon

Comment: Are you filling out the process and thread attributes of the CreateProcess function?  Can you show us that code?  Have you considered ShellExecuteEx instead?

Comment: Actually my parent application is launching DCOM server and I am trying to create the new process from DCOM module. Please see the code portion below.                                                  `// Create the process using modified stratup info
  int nRetVal = CreateProcess(
            (LPSTR)strFullPath.c_str(),
            (LPSTR)strCmdLine.c_str(),
            0,
         0,
         FALSE,
         0 ,
         0,
         (LPSTR)strWorkingDir.c_str(),
         //NULL,
         &StartupInfo,
         &ProcInfo
          );'

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ShellExecute()` function instead of `CreateProcess()`

Update:

- `CreateProcess()` creates a child process with same permissions, it's the most low-level API
- `ShellExecute/Ex()` delegates process creation to the shell (which can detect if the app requires privileges). If manifest allows running app as non-admin, pass `lpOperation=L"runas"` to elevate it manually
- `_wsystem()` creates a new `cmd.exe /c app.exe` process (I guess, via `CreateProcess`) thus delegating process creation to the Command Prompt

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The error you have describes the issue: *The Requested Operation Requires Elevation*. So you have to start with it:

- Are you sure your parent application has *full* administrative rights?
- Did it request elevation when you launched it?

Since you get the warning while building it, you must have an invalid manifest. [UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx) does not have `requestedPrivileges` element, it's rather `requestedExecutionLevel`:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel
    level="asInvoker|highestAvailable|requireAdministrator"
    uiAccess="true|false"
/>
```